# Why isn't python 3 the default python binary?

Tags: python3

I type `python` in a terminal window. I get Python 2.7 and not Python 3.5. According to the docs, Python 3.5 should come preloaded.

Comment: If you set up a virtual environment using: "python3 -m venv my-venv", then from any terminal activate that virtual environment by calling "source .../my-env/bin/activate", then python 3.5 will be the default in that terminal.  You can check the current default version by calling "python -V".

Comment: while your answer is helpful, i asked why.  not how to.  and, that is the big debate. here.  why should an older version by the default, instead of the current version.

Comment: You are exactly correct about my "comment"!  Which is why I wrote a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 58):

I don't know what "docs" you are reading nor what they say, but the `/usr/bin/python` is just a symbolic link to the default version of python, in this case 2.7, which is the result of just typing `python` on the terminal. This is the result of [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) which defines that

> - for the time being, **all distributions should ensure that `python` refers to the same target as `python2`**.

`type python` and `file /usr/bin/python` will confirm this.

The reason for this arrangement other than the convention, is that the source package [python-defaults in Xenial is the version 2.7.11](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/python-defaults), so the python symbolic link points to this version.

To use python 3 you have to be explicit and type `python3` in the command line, which is recommended in case you need an specific version, this can also be done with python 2, typing `python2`. Ubuntu includes both python 2 and 3 versions by default on all current versions.

There are [plans to migrate everything to python 3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python) and marking it as the default.

Comment: This is probably breaking rhythmbox-zeitgeist plugin which depends on zeitgeiigeist-python3 but could not  find it.

Comment: [**This is the doc**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#Python_3) that the OP means.

Answer (score 10):

To get the Python 3.5 REPL or run a script that's compatible, type `python3`. This is to maintain compatibility with all the legacy python 2.x (which has always been, and will remain linked to `python`).

The dash could find `python` if you set up a `.desktop` file for it (in `~/.local/share/applications/`), to open a terminal and start the REPL for instance. There isn't a default GUI REPL environment for python, and normal interface expectations are that the user would go to the terminal.

The talk of python 3.5 being default is the maintainers porting all system scripts from python 2.x over to python 3.x, not that python 3 would replace python 2 in all cases.

Comment: so, i guess the correct question is, how do i add python3 into my path, so that it executes automatically?

Comment: do you mean, how do you get python scripts to execute like a compiled program?

Comment: got it thanks.  just type python3 at the command prompt.

Comment: AIUI what to do with /usr/bin/python in the long term is still an open question. Best practice for python2 scripts would be to use python2 explicitly.

Comment: @PeterGreen Including the version will, of course, remain the best practice for python3 scripts even after it becomes the default --- who's ready for Python 4? ;-)

Comment: @givonz you can also add a #! /path/to/python3 to the first line of your python script, make it executable and run it by typing the name of the script without invoking python3 directly on the command line.

Comment: rather than using  `#!/usr/bin/python3` (or `#!/usr/bin/python2`) in scripts, better to use (just for python, specifically) `#!/usr/bin/env python3` if you want it to be remotely portable. For the most part, this is just documentation, since in many cases it will be called using `$ python3 your_pyprogram.py` anyway.

Answer (score 7):

You assume that the default Python should be available as `python`. That assumption is wrong.

It is an unlucky situation that obsolete Python 2 (`python`) comes first during shell <kbd>Tab</kbd>-expansion, before current and default Python 3 (`python3`) on systems which have both. The naming itself certainly does not help finding the default either, but there is a reason behind that.

On a system that comes with Python 3 “preloaded” and no Python 2 at all, there will be only `python3` and no `python`.

Code written for Python 3 should always look for an interpreter called `python3`. Code written for Python 2 will historically look for `python`.

This way, there will be no extra and unnecessary breakage, neither for new nor old scripts from any uncertainty of what `python` might point to.

There might come a point in time, possibly decades from now, where almost no-one remembers Python 2, when `python` might start to refer to `python3`. This would be purely for convenience, and can and should not be done premature, if at all! There is no hurry, because of the following impact:

“Current old” systems will have no knowledge of `python2`, only `python`, so it makes perfect sense to keep Python 2 code looking for `python`. This is the reason why `python` should refer to Python 2 for “as long as Python 2 code exists”.

New code written for Python 2, if that makes sense, can perfectly look for `python`. It might also look for `python2`, if it is intended to run only on Python 3 aware and well groomed systems (which might offer such link).

The benefit of Python 2 code using `python2` would be that it needs no extra touching once `python` starts referring to `python3`, which might never happen, or once `python` disappears at all, which might or might not happen. (That might come true, if Python 2 code dies out after hypothetical Python 4 becomes popular with its interpreter `python4`. – Because letting it point to either `python3` or `python4` would both be confusing.)

Note: The Arch Linux distribution did not follow the recommendation and lets `python` point to Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Python both 2.x, 3.x versions are available. if you call python as it is pointed to python 2.x it will load python 2.x

Below image will help you.

[image]

Comment: how do you type the same command and get 2 different results?

Comment: the different output from the second invocation of `python` is from using `<tab>` to query the autocompleter, which then outputs the possible permutations of `python*` and returns you to a new prompt.

Comment: @givonz , hmm I used TAB key bro. its not output. it is possible binary pattern.

Comment: Negative vote for what?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think that the answer should explain why the 2 first outputs are different and what is the role of  `apt-cache`, especially for Ubuntu beginners.

Comment: -1 This doesn't address the question of *why*.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.x  should work with 16.04 - Actually, it definitely WILL work. I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I have Python 3.4.3 - All you have to do to test it is type in `python3` and it should tell you what version you're running.

Comment: Well I wouldn't call using an OS computer science. And strictly speaking: Ubuntu is a Linux based OS and not Unix based.

Comment: i have yet to understand the diff bet linux & unix besides some command prompts & differently, but closely worded commands.  although the gui is far more advanced than what i see in solaris.

Comment: -1 This doesn't address the question of *why*.