# How to set Python 3 as default on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python3

According to the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/#Python_3) Ubuntu 16.04 uses Python 3 by default and should not even include include Python 2:

> ## Python 3
>
> Python2 is not installed anymore by default on the server, cloud and
> the touch images, long live Python3! Python3 itself has been upgraded
> to the 3.5 series.

However, the command line tells me that not only is Python 2 installed, it is actually the default interpreter:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What would be the correct way to set Python 3 as the default interpreter for the whole system?

Please do not ask me to create an alias in `.bashrc`, that is a lame workaround at best.

Comment: Like you wrote: *"Python2 is not installed anymore by default*  ***on the server, cloud and the touch images***. Would be silly not to include it on the desktop version, since it is still a widely used version. There was na excellent answer of @Braiam on this, will look it up... http://askubuntu.com/a/777104/72216