# apt-get failure while processing number of python packages

Tags: apt, python

How do I clean it up?

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-cairo
 python-gobject-2
 python-gtk2
 python-numpy
 python-sqlalchemy
 python-pygame
 childsplay
 childsplay-alphabet-sounds-ca
 python-pysqlite2
 gcompris
 python-configparser
 python-lzma
 python-sqlalchemy-ext
 youtube-dl
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
skumaran@hamming:~$
```

My full error log is here:

http://pastebin.com/1c6cZz34

How do I clean up my system so that it does not give this error while installing software.

My active python is python3.4

```
skumaran@hamming:~/workspace$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 3.4.5rc1
skumaran@hamming:~/workspace$ head -1 /usr/bin/pycompile 
#! /usr/bin/python
skumaran@hamming:~/workspace$
```

Comment: Please add the output of `/usr/bin/python --version` and `head -1 /usr/bin/pycompile` to your question.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch - added the requested information. I guess, I will have to switch to python2.7.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran You changed the `/usr/bin/python` symlink to point to Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu depends on `/usr/bin/python` being Python2. If you change this to Python3 you break the system. Change it back to Python2.

See [Why isn't python 3 the default python binary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777085/why-isnt-python-3-the-default-python-binary) and [How do I make the terminal run python 3.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14615/how-do-i-make-the-terminal-run-python-3-1) for more about this.

Comment: what's the best way to reset it it back to "system default" python?

Comment: `sudo ln -sf python2.7 /usr/bin/python` will change `/usr/bin/python` back to the default. Depending on what you did to make `/usr/bin/python` Python3.4 you may need to fix whatever you changed, too.