# Question about python3 under 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, python3

I thought python 3 is standards on ubuntu 16.04, but to use it I have to type 'python3'. Is there a way to use python instead and python2 for the old version?

Comment: This is still valid: http://askubuntu.com/questions/777085/why-isnt-python-3-the-default-python-binary

Answer (score 4):

`python` will always refer to `python2` unless the PEP-0394 makes any modification on this to state otherwise (or of course when Python 2 reaches EOL on 2020).

This is to conform to the PEP-0394 standard, [Which suggests](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/#id13):

- python2 will refer to some version of Python 2.x.
- python3 will refer to some version of Python 3.x.
- for the time being, all distributions should ensure that python refers to the same target as python2.

The relevant [Ubuntu WiKi on Python 3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3) mentions:

> /usr/bin/python will point to Python 3. No, this is not going to
>   happen (unless PEP 394 advocates otherwise, which is doubtful for the
>   foreseeable future). /usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python2 will point
>   to Python 2.7 and /usr/bin/python3 will point to the latest supported
>   Python 3 version.