# Error with Bazaar after installing Python 3.0: `except locale.Error, e:Cannot use bazaar`

Tags: bash, locale, bazaar

I cannot run any `bzr` command anymore after having updating Python 2.7 to Python 3.5

```
# bzr               
 File "/usr/bin/bzr", line 49
except locale.Error, e:
                   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Looking around line 49, one finds:

[image]

`LC_ALL` is set to an empty string.

Comment: Did you replace `/usr/bin/python` with Python3?

Comment: Exactly. I had version 2.7 and now use 3.5

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/777085/why-isnt-python-3-the-default-python-binary/ why this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Line 49 is `except locale.Error, e:` and in you screenshot it reads: `except locale.Erro-, e:`

Comment: Changing - to r does not change anything

Comment: It probably  worked before I installed Python3

Comment: oh, yes.  Python3 has a different syntax for exception handling: `except locale.Error as e:`

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that Python uses another syntax for expeption

- **Python2.7**: `except locale.Error, e:`
- **Python3**: `except locale.Error as e:`

It is possible to change the expression but I prefered changing the first line of `/usr/bin/bzr` from `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2.6` since my `python` command point to a +3.0 version.