# Cannot install python-gi

Tags: apt, python, dpkg, dependencies

I have ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.
After installing system I made this:

- update-alternatives --remove python /usr/bin/python2
- update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3

But now I cannot update the system, programms and packages, because of this problem:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово

Расчёт обновлений… Готово
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 6 пакетов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
Настраивается пакет python-gi (3.20.0-0ubuntu1) …
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-gi (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет alacarte:
 alacarte зависит от python-gi (>= 3.0), однако:
  Пакет python-gi пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета alacarte (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Настраивается пакет python-cairo (1.8.8-2) …
Отчёты apport не записаны, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                                                                                                           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-cairo (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет python-gi-cairo:
 python-gi-cairo зависит от python-gi (= 3.20.0-0ubuntu1), однако:
  Пакет python-gi пока не настроен.
 python-gi-cairo зависит от python-cairo, однако:
  Пакет python-cairo пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-gi-cairo (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Настраивается пакет python-gobject-2 (2.28.6-12ubuntu1) …
Отчёты apport не записаны, так достигнут MaxReports
                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-gobject-2 (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
Отчёты apport не записаны, так достигнут MaxReports
                                                   dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет python-gobject:
 python-gobject зависит от python-gi (>= 3.20.0-0ubuntu1), однако:
  Пакет python-gi пока не настроен.
 python-gobject зависит от python-gobject-2, однако:
  Пакет python-gobject-2 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-gobject (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Отчёты apport не записаны, так достигнут MaxReports
                                                   Обрабатываются триггеры для libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) …
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 python-gi
 alacarte
 python-cairo
 python-gi-cairo
 python-gobject-2
 python-gobject
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Help me plz to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undo your changes using

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove  python /usr/bin/python3 
sudo ln -s python2 /usr/bin/python
```

See [Why isn't python 3 the default python binary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777085/why-isnt-python-3-the-default-python-binary/) for why you shouldn't change `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Now I cannot run Terminal and "Programm updater"

Comment: @A.K, Ctrl+Alt+f1 to go tty1 console then Ctrl+Alt+f7 to go back to GUI

Comment: I installed terminatorx. But how to fix all dependencies?